# Remove PDF/A annotatio from PDDocument after merge

Tags: java, pdfbox

I use pdfbox and I want to merge PDF documents. This is not a problem. However, the second file uses the PDF/A annotation. After merging, this annotation is still part of the PDF file.

But I need to sign the document using AcroField, but with the annotation this is not possible.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Annotations and PDF/A are two different things. The PDF/A property is in the XMP metadata (do you need it?), however it is likely that it is no longer a valid PDF/A file after merge anyway. It is possible to sign a PDF/A file, what error message do you get? The easiest way to remove the XMP metadata would be to call `doc.getDocumentCatalog().setMetadata(null)` but then you lose all XMP metadata, the question is whether you want that.

Comment: Your solution works. The mistake was that I was filling it with an empty metadata instance. And the signature app was giving me an error that it was requesting the length of the metadata. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations and PDF/A are two different things. The PDF/A property is in the XMP metadata, however it is likely that it is no longer a valid PDF/A file after merge anyway.

The easiest way to remove the XMP metadata (if you don't need it) is to call `doc.getDocumentCatalog().setMetadata(null)`.

If a more fine-tuned approach is needed, one can combine the `ExtractMetadata.java` example (gets the xmp metadata) with the `CreatePDFA.java` example (saves the metadata) and try to call `xmp.removeSchema(xmp.getPDFExtensionSchema())`.